# Unhandled Runtime Error Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child

Tags: arrays, dropdown, antd

when i add two or more array for dropdown it shows " Unhandled Runtime Error

Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child."

```
import React from "react";
import { Table, Input ,Dropdown, menu,menuProps,Button,Space} from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { DownOutlined, SearchOutlined , UserOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const Example = () => {


    const items = [
        
        {
          label:'1st menu item',
          key: '1',
        },
        {
          label: '2nd menu item',
          key: '1',
        },
        
        {
          label: '3rd menu item',
          key: '1',
          
        },
        
        
      ];
    const item = [
        {
            label:'zm',
            key: '2',
          },
          {
            label: 'zm',
            key: '2',
          },
    ];
    return(
    <div>
        <h1>hello</h1>
    
                    <Dropdown menu= {{items,}} trigger={['click']}>
                        <a onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
                            <Space>
                                Select Property
                                <DownOutlined />
                            </Space>
                        </a>
                    </Dropdown>
                    <Dropdown menu= {{item,}} trigger={['click']}>
                        <a onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}><Space>Select Property<DownOutlined/></Space></a>
                    </Dropdown>                         
    </div>
    );
}
export default Example;
```

i want two dropdown list with 2different content. ps:already tried removing space in between but its hows same error

Comment: It is working fine here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-antd-form-forked-wc2qul .

Comment: No its not did you click on the second dropdown

Comment: You didn't specify the antd version. Looks like you have installed antd v4.x and following antd v5.x docs. In antd 5 dropdown, menu expects an object whereas in antd 4, `overlay` prop is used to pass a single react element `<Dropdown overlay={<Menu items={[]}  />} ></Dropdown>`.

Comment: Muhammad Nouman Rafique but the above code works with  > =  4 .24.0

Answer (score 5):

if I look at the documentation, to name the list data variable the menu must be named 'items', an error will occur if using a variable name other than 'items'

or you can use like this `items={{ items: [ { label:'1st menu item', key: '1', }, ] }}` so you can use other name variable not only use items variable.

if you want to custome name variable, you can use

```
const custome = [ { label:'1st menu item', key: '1', }, ]
```

and then you can use inside dropdown

```
<Dropdown menu= {{items: custome }} trigger={['click']}>
```

or you can use like this

```
items={{ items: [ { label:'1st menu item', key: '1', }, ] }}
```

so you can use other name variable not only use items variable